# Wordpress: is there any way to display posts in TR TD formate instead of DIV SPAN

Tags: php, wordpress

Wordpress: is there any way to display posts in TR TD formate instead of DIV SPAN

let suppose my content is like

```
<table>
<tr>
<td> col1 </td>
<td> col2 </td>
</tr> 
<tr>
<td> val1 </td>
<td> val2 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

the out comes like this

```
<div>
<span>col1</span><br>

<span>col2</span><br>

<span>val1</span><br>

<span>val2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: its all css you can easily do that

Comment: Some times wp not breaking div sapn in correct place so i need data should display in tr td format.